# pyspark splitting words into rows

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying out pyspark and looking at this example:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

I got the code working easy enough, so the guide is pretty good, but one part has got me scratching my head which is the split part

```
words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)
```

I get what it is doing, it's splitting each row by space and turning each word into a row. But I would have expected something along the lines of this

```
words = lines.explode(lambda l: l.split(" ")).alias("word")
```

In the code they have lines.value, lines is the dataframe and value is the column name. Why are we pulling the value from the data frame? How does it know what row we are pulling the value from? Shouldn't we have a row object (l in the second example) and be pulling value from that?

My other question is how is it that dataframe has a function/property called "value". If I change the column name to "bob" then dataframe suddenly appears to have a function/property "bob". Is this a python feature where objects can have dynamic functions?

It appears the actual split function is not the python split function but a function provided by pyspark libraries (there is an import at the top). Why did they do it this way?

Comment: lines.value and lines["value"] represent the same column. It is just specifying the column name to pass to the split function. Here's nice website to go over pyspark. https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark-tutorial/

Comment: That makes sense. I see you can also specify it as `$"value"` and `col("value")`. (At least you can in Scala, I switched to Scala).